# Forever monitor fails to run inside a docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, sails.js, dockerfile, forever

I am trying to deploy my `sails.js` based webapp in a docker container, in which I want to use `forever` to run the `app.js` instead of using `sails lift`. I have the docker container built based on the following **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN npm install -g sails mongodb forever pm2
RUN  mkdir -p /host
WORKDIR /host
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 1337
#CMD sails lift
#CMD PORT=1337 forever start app.js --prod
CMD forever start app.js --prod
```

As soon as I start the docker container, it goes down almost immediately, however, if I change it to use `CMD sails lift`, the container stays up okay.

So I am wondering if it is possible to use forever to serve node.js app in a docker container, if so, how? or what might be wrong with my **Dockerfile**?

**Edit:**

Docker logs for the problematic docker container (not much information though):

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: app.js
```

Comment: Did you try looking at the logs?

Comment: yes, just added it in my original post. Thanks